# Youtube_player_flutter not playing video on iOS device

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I would like to play a YouTube video in the background of my app on a certain page. This means the video/the player shouldn't be visible. Just for the audio.

The package is called youtube_player_flutter ^4.1.0.
I've tested the same code on an android device and it works. However on Ios it doesn't and after I go back to the previous page I receive this error message:

```
iOS => call stop, playerId 02a9ae4c-0fac-482d-a9f6-d668feffa2da

[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(evaluateJavaScript_failed, Failed evaluating JavaScript, JavaScript string was: 'loadById("RMPX_vgqQnM", 0)'
Error Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=3 "The WKWebView was invalidated" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The WKWebView was invalidated})
#0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:564:7)
#1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:316:33)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      MethodChannelWebViewPlatform.evaluateJavascript (package:webview_flutter/src/webview_method_channel.dart:90:21)
#3      WebViewController.evaluateJavascript (package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart:626:39)
#4      YoutubePlayerController._evaluateJS (package:youtube_player_flutter/src/youtube_player.dart:553:30)
#5      YoutubePlayerController.load (package:youtube_player_flutter/src/youtube_player.dart:572:7)
#6      _YoutubePlayerState.listener (package:youtube_<…>
```

The following code is working on android:

```
YoutubePlayer(
  context: context,
  videoId: _videoId,
  flags: YoutubePlayerFlags(
    hideControls: true,
    autoPlay: true,
  ),
  onPlayerInitialized: (YoutubePlayerController controller) {
    _videoController = controller;
    debugPrint("playing...");
  },
)
```

I would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1):

İos simulators have a awkward resistance to youtube players. Trying it on a real device might help

Comment: Same on real device too.

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines to Info.plist

```
<key>io.flutter.embedded_views_preview</key>
<true/>
```

may help you